# How can I create a function in .js file and add it to another .js file?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am working with chrome extension. I want to create a function in my current content.js, then add the function to another.js file

I have created a new script in content.js using this code:

```
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('another.js');
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

(I have another.js in the same directory)

Now, if I am in content.js, is there a way to create a new function myfunction() and add it to another.js file (from content.js) ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file this might help.

Comment: The code inside a `<script>` element is no longer a content script. It's a [page script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) that runs in the page context, not in the *isolated world* of content scripts. Depending on your goal, you probably don't need to create a script element at all - just declare a global function and it'll be shared between all active content scripts in that tab. Alternatively, if you really want a page context function, you'll have to put all the code that uses it into a script element as well.